# Wordpress wpadminbar not setting up its style

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am currently working on a wordpress theme and I have a little problem in my page.

The wpadminbar element is not setting up its style. I have no idea why it is, but it is.

Screen shot:

[image: wpadminbar error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you done any debugging with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (a Firefox plugin)? Which styles does your page load?

From a screenshot this one is a bit hard to solve.

First guess: you forgot to add the link to the main WP CSS (called admin-bar.css) in your theme's header.

Comment: ty! that was the problem. i didn't know you had to add the style for that. But, I looked for admin-bar.css and I only found an admin-bar.php

Comment: oh. nvm. i found it. it's in wp-includes/css/admin-bar.css

Comment: In my installation of Wordpress (3.1) it's in `wp-includes/css/admin-bar.css`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and added this to the header template:

```
<?php

/* Always have wp_head() just before the closing </head>
 * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
 * generally use this hook to add elements to <head> such
 * as styles, scripts, and meta tags.
 */
wp_head();
?></head>
```

Comment: this is the correct answer indeed. `wp_head()` will automatically insert HTML needed to style the admin bar only if the admin is logged in. Btw: don't forget to add `<?php wp_footer() ?>` right before the closing `</body>` tag, cause that's where the actual HTML for the admin bar will get loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using firebug on it to find where the CSS file is? If it's on the server it's time to narrow it down in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have wp_deregister_style('open-sans'); in your theme it can be the reason of this!